# Error Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

Tags: html

estoy de cabeza con la importacion de datos desde un archivo excel, leyendo la documentacion oficial pude llegar a este codigo en mi controlador:

```
 public function store(Request $request){

        $path = $request->file('serie')->getRealPath();

        $data = Excel::import(new SerializacionImport, $path);

        dd($data);

            //return $data;

        //return ('hola');

    }
```

y mi formulario basico:

```
 <form action="{{ route('serializacion') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="serie">Seleccione Archivo de series</label>
        <input type="file" name="serie" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="subir">
   </form>
```

pero cuando cargo el archivo excel, me sale el bendito error:  **Call to a member function getRealPath() on null** , lo que segun entiendo seria que no esta llegando ningun archivo, por eso con el dd trato de ver que llega, pero tampoco me imprime el dd para verificar.

He probado de cambiar rutas, he hecho diferentes archivos y aun asi nada.

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Si querés enviar archivos en un formulario tendría que tener el atributo `enctype='multipart/form-data'`. Es algo más de html que de laravel

Comment: gracias chicos, me estaba olvidanto del enctype en el formulario, por lo menos ahora ya me muestra algo diferente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres enviar archivos en un formulario html, la etiqueta `<form>` debería que tener el atributo `enctype='multipart/form-data'`.
El atributo `enctype` especifica cómo se deben codificar los datos del formulario al enviarlos al servidor.
Y el valor `multipart/form-data` quiere decir que no hay caracteres codificados. Este valor es obligatorio cuando utiliza formularios que tienen un control de carga de archivos.

Nota: El atributo enctype solo se puede utilizar si method = "post".

Para que profundices sobre esto, puedes leer a detalle los atributos de un [formulario HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-enctype)